# act_as_tenant with child records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a Rails project with `act_as_tenant`.  At the moment, I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_tenant :organization
  has_many :holdings
end
```

Additionally, I have this Holding model:

```
class Holding < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :portfolio
end
```

`act_as_tenant` is working correctly for the Portfolio model.  That is, if I am logged in as an organization that does not match the Portfolio's organization, that Portfolio won't exist in the database.

However, as I am logged in as a different organization, I can still access the Holding.  But when I try to do `holding.portfolio`, I get `nil`.

Is there a way to extend this sort of `act_as_tenant` logic so that all child models of a parent model will automatically be scoped by tenant as well?

Comment: according to document: `Adding acts_as_tenant to your model declaration will scope that model to the current tenant BUT ONLY if a current tenant has been set.` So i think you need to set `ActsAsTenant.current_tenant = current_organization`

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation for `acts_as_tenant`:

```
Row-level multitenancy each model must have a tenant ID column on it. This makes it easy to filter records for each tenant using your standard database columns and indexes. ActsAsTenant uses row-level multitenancy.
```

What this implies that also the holding model should have `acts_as_tenant :organization` and have a foreign key to organization. This should be the case also for other records you plan to add that are dependent on `acts_as_tenant`